# What are the common use case when I need to use UUID as primary key for Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, uuid

I was studying some [opensourced Rails](http://github.com/assemblymade/meta) project and saw that they use UUID as primary keys instead of IDs. I saw on some blog posts that it [loses the sequentiality that comes with auto-increment](http://labria.github.io/2013/04/28/rails-4-postgres-uuid-pk-guide/) like we had with IDs.

I then try to find whether it is necessary to use UUID as table. I saw some benefits being illustrated by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605377/why-use-apps-for-generating-custom-uuid-instead-database-id), but he mentioned it is seldom worth it to use UUID unless the website has high traffic and multiple database servers.

So I am wondering in real life, is it worth it to implement UUID as primary from the start for an ecommerce app in Rails? Especially since Rails 4 now can support uuid out of the box.

Comment: Jeff Atwood has a [pretty good writeup](http://blog.codinghorror.com/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids/) on the pros and cons of guids

Comment: Is there any point if i have both sequential ID and GUID in the same table?

Comment: I don't think so - you would get all the problems associated with a sequential ID (parallel processes assigning the same ID for example, replication etc) plus all the downsides of a GUID - storage space, computational cost of generating GUIDs.

Comment: Its worth being noted that MongoDB uses GUID:s per default.

Comment: so must I use UUID if I have more than one databases (e.g. a master slave setting) ?

Comment: It is a common way to solve the issue of assigning ID's while using serveral databases. Another common alternative is using read only mirrored database(s) for faster read operations and a separate "master" database for write operations.